# How to get computed values from formula cells using ExcelJs. It is returning formula instead of value that I am on seeing on excel

Tags: node.js, excel-formula, exceljs

I am reading an excel file using ExcelJs. However, when I got formula cells, It is not giving me value but giving formula.
Can any body help please.

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
var FormulaParser = require('hot-formula-parser').Parser;
var parser = new FormulaParser();

workbook.xlsx.readFile('test.xlsx').then(function() {
var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(2);
var row = worksheet.getRow(1);
console.log(row.getCell(1).value); //5
console.log(row.getCell(2).value); //8
console.log(row.getCell(3).value); // =IFERROR(MIN(MAX($A1-$B1,0),$E1),"")
console.log(row.getCell(3).text); // blank
//I also tried with using FormulaParser library as below but getting null.

console.log(parser.parse(row.getCell(3).formula).result); // null
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The result is here:

```
console.log(row.getCell(3).result);
```